# Using a callback function with Google Geocode

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, asynchronous, geocoding

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now, and even after reading several examples on Stack I've been unable to get this working.  It doesn't help that I'm a JS newbie.

I'm trying to retrieve information about an address from the Google Geocoder API, and then pass the object over to another function.  Per my reading I understand that function I'm using to retrieve the information is asynchronous, and therefore I need to use a callback function to read it.  However, when I attempt to do this I still get 'undefined' returned by my console.  I know that the information is coming from Google fine, since when I use console.log() on the result object it returns correctly.

Anyways, here's what I'm working with:

```
function onSuccess(position) {
  getLocationData(position, function(locationData) {
    console.log(locationData);
  });   
}

function getLocationData(position, callback) {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var location = 'Billings,MT';

  if( geocoder ) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': location }, function (results, status) {
      if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
        return results[0];
      }
    });
  }
  callback();
}
```

Like I mentioned though, all I get with this is 'undefined'.  If I put 'console.log(results[0])' above the getLocationData() return, the object returned is correct though.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is, that you didn't connect the callback to the return. As the `geocode()` function itself is already asynchronous, the `return` doesn't have any effect there. Instead you have to pass the values you are returning here directly to the callback-function. Like this:

```js
function getLocationData(position, callback) {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var location = 'Billings,MT';

  if( geocoder ) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': location }, function (results, status) {
      if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
        callback(results[0]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```